# Regex to find all the img tags with http url

Tags: java, javascript, regex

I have is javascript regex to extract all the `<img>` tags that have the `src` as `http://....`  from a string.

```
regex = /<img[^>]+src="?(http:\/\/[^">]+)"?\s*\/>/g;
```

My question is how to do this in Java, and secondly the above regex only gives the content of `src`, I want to extract and replace the whole `<img>` with blank spaces.

---

PS. The may have many other properties also along with the src, like 'class', 'alt' etc.

Comment: str = str.replaceAll("<img[^>]+src="?(http:\/\/[^">]+)"?\s*\/>", "");

Comment: Just fyi, you can do this without a regex in javascript. `document.querySelectorAll('img[src^="http"]')` will return all `img` elements that have `src` beginning with `http`. Also, probably it would be easier to use java's xml parsing tools for this.

Comment: @parchment : doing it in javascript is out of question now, I want to achieve the it in Java now.

Comment: @яша : It's not that easy brother.

Comment: @AnasAzeem You can do the same thing using [this library](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) or just use [jaxp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/)

Comment: you want to fix the regex query? I don't really understand what is your objective?

Comment: @яша: I want the Java alternative.

Answer (score 3):

```
//Try this solution:

//This answer was tested I hope it is what you're looking for :

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<img?(.+)?\\s*\\/>");
Matcher m = p.matcher("<img src=\"http://google.com\"/>");

if(m.find())
System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

Comment: @AnasAzeem if you find this solution helpful please accept it as your answer

Comment: Sure, let me check first.

Comment: It doesn't work with this `<img class="imageViewerInLarge" src="http://goqii-app.s3.amazonaws.com/conversation/1405488401_100X100.png" alt="" />&nbsp;Tester tester&nbsp;<img src="smiley_yell" alt="" />&nbsp;smiley tester<br /><br />` string

Comment: Moreover I wanted to have the whole img tag extracted not just the url.

Comment: you mean download the whole image ?

Comment: ok first let's finish from the regex check it I have edited it

Comment: No it doesn't work. I don't want to download the image, I just want the whole img tag to be extracted (not just the src of it). Example - `<img class="imageViewerInLarge" src="http://goqii-app.s3.amazonaws.com/conversation/1405488401_100X100.png" alt="" />&nbsp;Tester tester&nbsp;<img src="smiley_yell" alt="" />&nbsp;smiley tester<br /><br />`, the thing I want to extract is `<img class="imageViewerInLarge" src="http://goqii-app.s3.amazonaws.com/conversation/1405488401_100X100.png" alt="" />`. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: It successfully extracted the src. Any suggestions on how to extract the whole tag

Comment: @Anas Azeem Aa so you want everything together in one string including class, alt etc...?

Comment: Please reply, we are just there.

Comment: Answer my question please

Comment: Yeah, everything which is between `<img ... src="http..." ...... />` is to be extracted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57385/discussion-between-anas-azeem-and-).

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

`regex = /(<img[^>]+src="?http:\/\/[^">]+"?[^>]+\/>)/g`

it should get all img tags. (changed the end of regexp and moved brackets around img tag)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below segment

`.*(<img\s+.*src\s*=\s*"([^"]+)".*>).*`

here it will create two matches 
1. Match 1 would be the complete img tag 
2. Match 2 will hold the URL of image only.

Example

```
package com.company;
```

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String htmlFragment = "<img src='http://img01.ibnlive.in/ibnlive/uploads/2015/11/Videocon-Delite.gif' width='90' height='62'>Videocon Mobile Phones has launched three new Android smartphones - Z55 Delite, Z45 Dazzle, and Z45 Amaze with prices starting at Rs 4,599.";

    Pattern pattern =
            Pattern.compile( ".*(<img\\s+.*src\\s*=\\s*'([^']+)'.*>).*" );
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( htmlFragment );
    if( matcher.matches()) {
        String match =  matcher.group(1);
        String match1 =  matcher.group(2);

        //match.replaceAll("'","");
        System.out.println(match);
        System.out.println(match1);
        //System.out.println(match2);

        String newString = htmlFragment.replaceAll(match,"");
        System.out.println(newString);

    }


}
```

}

The example is with a single quote image url , but the provided regex at the top is for your case with double inverted quotes.